# importing from index.ts in same folder

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-5

I was wondering if I could import my files from a `index.ts` in the same folder.

e.g.

**/src/index.ts**

```
export * from './services';
```

**/src/services/index.ts**

```
export * frome './service1.ts';
export * frome './service2.ts';
...
```

but now i'd like to do the following

**/src/app.component.ts**

```
import {Service1} from '.';
```

but this doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

UPDATE:
a service is just a export of a class:

```
export class Service1 {
   // code
}
```

Comment: did you solve the problem? how?

Comment: Nope I wasn't able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

How are you exporting services from  **service1 && service2** files? If you are using `export default` then it will  not for you. Instead of using `default` you should export it explicitly

```
export const Service1 = () => {};
```

Then you will be able to import your `service1` like below

```
import { Service1 } from './services';
```

Comment: @Kiwi what doesnt work now? have you tried to create instanse of `const foo = new Service1()` ?